# Auto size div and right aligned div in same div container

Tags: html, css

In the snippet below, I want the "title" div to size itself based on its content, so I don't have to specify a width. That bit is obviously working already. I then want the "rightside" div to take the remaining space and right align itself - at the moment it just sits next to the title div.

And of course I don't want to use floats because that messes up everything and we have a no floats policy here.

Based on reading other threads I thought adding an overflow:hidden to one of the parents would make it do this but I can't get it working.

I don't want to specify a width for either div but it will always be the case that one of the parents will have a width specified, so in this case I've set it on the "outer" element.

So how do we get "rightside" to appear to the right of the red box ? thanks

```css
.outer {
  width:500px;
  border:1px solid red;
}

.outer div {
  display:inline-block;
  border:1px solid green;
}

.rightside {
  width:auto;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">

    <div class="title">
      Autosize this section based on content
    </div>
    <div class="rightside">
      Right align this
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: read abou flexbox and you can easily do this

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, they all seem to work so I chose the first as accepted answer. It took me a while to implement the change as display:flex seemed to change some padding behaviours, but got there in the end ! thanks again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use flexbox or grid to solve this kind of problems its easy and fast

flex example

```css
.outer {
  width:500px;
  border:1px solid red;
 
}
.inner {
   display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  justify-content:space-between;
}
.outer div {
/*   display:inline-block; */
  border:1px solid green;
}

.rightside {
  width:auto;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">

    <div class="title">
      Autosize this section based on content
    </div>
    <div class="rightside">
      Right align this
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and grid

```css
.outer {
  width:500px;
  border:1px solid red;
 
}
.inner {
  display:grid;
grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  justify-content:space-between;
}
.outer div {
/*   display:inline-block; */
  border:1px solid green;
}

.rightside {
  width:auto;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">

    <div class="title">
      Autosize this section based on content
    </div>
    <div class="rightside">
      Right align this
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox will help!

```css
.outer {
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.outer .title,
.outer .rightside {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.inner {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">

    <div class="title">
      Autosize this section based on content
    </div>
    <div class="rightside">
      Right align this
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you would like the rightside to fill the rest of the space, you could use `flexbox` and `flex-grow`, like this:

```
.inner {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.inner div {
  display:inline-block;
  border:1px solid green;
  width: auto;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.rightside {
  width:auto;
  text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With **flexbox**, you only need to set `display: felx;` for the parent element, and `margin-left: auto;` for the rightside (child) element :

```css
div {
  border: 2px dotted silver;
  padding: .5em;
}

/* ---------------- */

.parent {
  display: flex;
}

.rightside {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>
    Child 1
  </div>
  <div class="rightside">
    Child 2
  </div>
</div>
```